# Can we access iphone's filesystem to backup data without iOS starting - iOS wont boot due to lack of disk space

Tags: iphone, ios, filesystem

I have the problem most people have with iPhone X - when the storage gets full, the Os eventually fails and won't start since it needs space.
I did not backup my data (photos mainly) and wondering if there is a way to access the filesystem and just take a dump of the filesystem?

Most tools expect the OS to be working which is understandable, but there should be a way. Either I can plug in external storage (and mount) of some sort for the OS to boot up or access filesystem and delete all the app files except for photos.

Or copy all the files, run an emulator with more space? Just thinking out loud here. Not an expert.

These things are surely possible in Android, I wonder if anyone has done it on iOS. The idiot that I am to not have backup enabled, I also find it silly the way this works.

Any help is much appreciated!

EDIT: FYI, i tried the iTunes update option and it doesn't work - and I do not want to reset.

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/81938

Comment: Essentially you're asking to open an encrypted hardware device without the software/OS necessary to run the decryption. If it was that easy, there would be no security.

Comment: No, I am asking if I could emulate that and run it on another piece of hardware to boot my OS successfully, which is a perfectly valid assumption. The question is whether Apple is designed to let me do that.

Comment: One non-kosher option: *theoretically* you could jailbreak and load your own filesystem-browser OS with checkm8 but I don't think there exists any such software at the moment

Comment: Emulate what? The encryption keys are in the hardware, in a separate secure enclave. No amount of external brute force is going to get around that. After the FBI paid a foreign company several million dollars to do just that to an old iPhone 4, the door was closed.